# When script carries common strings from rows, lines are truncated

Tags: bash, shell, script, awk

I have this script

```
BEGIN {
  OFS=FS=";"
}
ARGIND == 1 {
   map[$2] = ($2 in map ? map[$2] OFS : "") $1
   next
}
{
   r = $0;
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i in map)
         r = r OFS map[$i]
   $0 = r
}
1
```

and this

```
#! /usr/bin/awk  -f

BEGIN {
  OFS=FS=";"
  C=0;
}
{
  if (ARGIND == 1) {
     X = $NF
     T0[$NF] = C++
     $NF = ""
     if (T1[X]) {
        T1[X] = T1[X] $0
     } else {
        T1[X] = $0
     }
  } else {
     X = $NF
     T0[$NF] = C++
     $NF = ""
     if (T2[X]) {
        T2[X] = T2[X] $0
     } else {
        T2[X] = $0
     }
  }
}

END {
  for (X in T0) {
    # concatenate T1[X] and X, since T1[X] ends with ";"
    print T1[X]  X, T2[X]
  }
}
```

I use it in this way

```
awk -f join2.awk g2.txt g1.txt
```

This script works well if g1.txt and g2.txt are so

g1.txt

```
alfa beta;www.google.com
Light Dweller - CR, Technical Metal;http://alfa.org;http://beta.org;http://gamma.org;
```

g2.txt

```
Jack to ride.zip;http://alfa.org;
JKr.rui.rar;http://gamma.org;
Nofj ogk.png;http://gamma.org;
```

it generates this output g3.txt correctly

```
alfa beta;www.google.com
Light Dweller - CR, Technical Metal;http://alfa.org;http://beta.org;http://gamma.org;;Jack to ride.zip;JKr.rui.rar;Nofj ogk.png
```

BUT same script truncate strings and works problematically if my g1.txt & g2.txt are written so

g1.txt

```
alfa beta;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=297585;
Light Dweller;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869;
Imp - Alp;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=340249;
```

g2.txt

```
Link;1996 7.zip;https://yd.k/d/BbNUb-2yhVmVnw;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869&st=30;
Link;Moonblo (Tape)_123.zip;https://yd.k/d/57i;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869&st=30;
Link;Moonblo(Demo) [1996].rar;https://yd.k/d/A7U;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869;
```

it give me THIS WRONG output

```
alfa beta;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=297585;;;
Light Dweller;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869;;;
Imp - Alp;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=340249;;;
```

BUT I want this CORRECT OUTPUT

```
alfa beta;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=297585;
Light Dweller;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869;Link;1996 7.zip;https://yd.k/d/BbNUb-2yhVmVnw;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869&st=30;Link;Moonblo(Demo) [1996].rar;https://yd.k/d/A7U;
Imp - Alp;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=340249;
```

**Why this output?**
Because `https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869` it must carry the entire line where it is in g2.txt ON the line where it is IN the g1.txt text file, i.e ==> g1.txt row ==> `Light Dweller;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869`

Comment: So `https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869` should be treated same as `https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869&st=30` ?

Comment: @anubhava yes, exactly, for every link that have `&st=30`, `&st=60`, `&st=90`, `&st=120`.. etc but I see that is not the only problem because I try also to remove link with &st=30 and script had problems. Is something about text in my example

Comment: ok I will look into that again